# aiohttp: infinite streaming with long wait periods

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to connect to a REST API which will stream data infinitely when events are happening. In the meantime no data is sent through the API.

I have the following code:

```
async with self.client_session.get(
  self._url(path),
  headers=self._headers,
  timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=0, connect=0, sock_connect=0, sock_read=0),
) as response:
  async for message in response.content:
    # do something
```

Every ~10 minutes I receive the error `Unexpected exception: ClientPayloadError('Response payload is not completed')` from `aiohttp`.

Is there a possibility to achieve that? Yes, I have another while around that which restarts the whole process currently; however, doing this every ~10 minutes is not too efficient.

Comment: HTTP GET requests typically don't lend themselves well to long lasting connections. Better to use websockets instead for something like this. Webhooks might also be a good solution if your process is event driven.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, i am not the owner of the API, and their specification follows W3C Server-Sent Events (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events). They specify it as a GET endpoint that returns JSON merge patches for updates.